# Application running from VC++ 6 crashes with "kernelbase.dll module not found"

Tags: visual-c++

This happens only in a specific machine.

So it must be VS 6 installation in the machine or the machine itself.

If I run the application in VC++6, I will get a crash with "kernelbase.dll module not found " after a certain operation.

But when executed in standalone, it is running fine.

Has anybody experience this symptom? Do I have to reinstall VC++6 again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by reorganizing system path. By some of unnecessary directories from the system path, I could resolve this problem. Hope this will help others with a similar problem.